# What does execute() return?

Tags: ex-mode, functions

In the function-list, it gives execute() as running an ex command, but it does not seem to be returning a string as I expect.

For example, if I run this on a file that has 'abc' in it somewhere:

```
:echo execute("%s/abc//gen")
```

Then it answers: "1 match on 1 line". Then if make the following command:

```
:echo str2nr("1 match on 1 line")
```

Then it returns the number 1 on the status line. However, finally, if I run this:

```
:echo str2nr(execute("%s/abc//gen"))
```

Then it returns 0 on the status line, not 1 as expected. What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that the result of `execute("%s/abc//gen")` is not the same as the string `"1 match on 1 line"`, but `"\n1 match on 1 line"`. When you echo this, it outputs as expected, but with `str2nr`, the initial newline  leads to your unexpected 0 return value.

As is described in `:help execute()`, you can use split to get a list of lines of the output. So, this should work:

```
echo str2nr(join(split(execute('%s/abc//gen'), "\n")))
```

Comment: Huh, how could I have determined the exact string that execute is returning? Is there a way to print out the string with unprintable characters shown as codes?

Comment: I'm not sure about showing unprintable characters, but you can see the output with something like `:echo 'x' . func(...) . 'y'`.